# CPU Fan always on high speed after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: asus, cpu, fan

cpu fan always on high speed after update from 13.10 to 14.04

MB Asus P5G41T-M LX V2

It was working nice on 13.10

Output of `sensors`:

```
atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:      +1.17 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.60 V)
 +3.3 Voltage:      +3.39 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
 +5 Voltage:        +5.17 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
 +12 Voltage:      +12.20 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU FAN Speed:      922 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
CHASSIS FAN Speed:    0 RPM  (min =  600 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
CPU Temperature:    +42.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
MB Temperature:     +35.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +54.0°C  (high = +78.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +54.0°C  (high = +78.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +79.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +130.0°C, hyst =  +2.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
```

Comment: how can we close this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to shutup my fans in ubuntu using pwmcontrol according to this HOW TO
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=42737

Although it was a different Ubuntu version (I believe) it should hopefully work on 14.04.
It's worth the shot.

Comment: i opened my machine for a check and confirmed that it was the nvidia fan that was making all that noise, solved the noise by replacing the video driver with the nvidia proprietary one.
thanks for sugestions.